# Data is graphing in Excel 2010, but not in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I'm using VBA to graph data in a program I created in Excel 2010. I sent it to another computer, which has Excel 2013 instead, and I found that everything worked perfectly except for this graphing issue.

My code will create the graphs, and size them perfectly, but it won't actually graph any of the data points. In my code, I also add and delete series, and I notice that the number of series is correct on the side, but that the series didn't retain the custom names I gave them.

But here's the twist. When I right click on the chart and click "select data", all of the data immediately pops up, including all of my custom names for the series. I don't even go into select data or anything. The moment I click it, all of the values just pop up immediately.

[Here is an imgur album of what it looks like before/after. Note that I do absolutely nothing other than right click and select the option "select data".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUexq.jpg) It's like the data is already selected, but just doesn't show up until I click 'select data".

Why would Excel 2013 be doing this? How do I make these values actually show up via VBA methods? I'll add a sample of the graphing code I use below.

```
'Setting the range the chart will cover

Set rngChart = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Counter + 3, 4), Cells(Counter + 27, 10))

'Dimensioning the chart and choosing chart type

Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter, rngChart.Cells(1).Left, rngChart.Cells(1).Top, rngChart.Width, rngChart.Height)
Set cht = co.Chart
Set sc = cht.SeriesCollection

'Remove any default series

Do While sc.Count > 0
    sc(1).Delete
Loop

'Setting chart data

'Series 1
With sc.NewSeries
    .Name = "=Sheet1!$C$1"
    .XValues = "=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$" & SimpleTracker + 1
    .Values = "=Sheet2!$B$2:$B$" & SimpleTracker + 1
    .MarkerSize = 3
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle

End With

'Series 2
With sc.NewSeries
    .Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
    .XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$" & Counter + 1
    .Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$" & Counter + 1
    .MarkerSize = 5
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
    .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 10
    .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 10
End With


'Setting chart labels
With cht
    .HasTitle = True
    If n = 0 Then
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Simple Fit - CFL Over Time"
    ElseIf Range("I" & n) = "Regression Title" Then
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Range("J" & n).Text
    Else
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Simple Fit - CFL Over Time"
    End If
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    If DayTracker = 1 Then
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Days)"
    ElseIf HourTracker = 1 Then
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Hours)"
    Else
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Minutes)"
    End If
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = True
End With
```

I also want to note that this code still works perfectly in Excel 2010, and that the graphing still works there. It just doesn't work in Excel 2013.

Thank you for reading! If you have any questions or need any clarification, just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
With sc.NewSeries
```

with

```
With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
```

I had the same issue in Excel 2013. I don't know why, but this solution works for me.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I wonder why it fixes it? Thank you though! I knew somebody would've had this problem before I did!

Comment: That's funny. I don't know why it fixed the problem, but I know I've never used a variable to reference SeriesCollection. Maybe long ago I had a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

The short story is I wasn't able to replicate the misbehavior.

The long story: I assumed that your code was the body of a Sub, so I created a module that contained the following:

```
Sub DoItOriginal()
    'Setting the range the chart will cover

    Set rngChart = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Counter + 3, 4), Cells(Counter + 27, 10))

    'Dimensioning the chart and choosing chart type

    Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter, rngChart.Cells(1).Left, rngChart.Cells(1).Top, rngChart.Width, rngChart.Height)
    Set cht = co.Chart
    Set sc = cht.SeriesCollection

    'Remove any default series

    Do While sc.Count > 0
        sc(1).Delete
    Loop

    'Setting chart data

    'Series 1
    With sc.NewSeries
        .Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
        .XValues = "=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$" & SimpleTracker + 1
        .Values = "=Sheet2!$B$2:$B$" & SimpleTracker + 1
        .MarkerSize = 3
        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle

    End With

    'Series 2
    With sc.NewSeries
        .Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
        .XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$" & Counter + 1
        .Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$" & Counter + 1
        .MarkerSize = 5
        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 10
        .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 10
    End With


    'Setting chart labels
    With cht
        .HasTitle = True
        If n = 0 Then
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Simple Fit - CFL Over Time"
        ElseIf Range("I" & n) = "Regression Title" Then
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Range("J" & n).Text
        Else
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Simple Fit - CFL Over Time"
        End If
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        If DayTracker = 1 Then
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Days)"
        ElseIf HourTracker = 1 Then
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Hours)"
        Else
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Minutes)"
        End If
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL"
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Next, I needed some data to work with, so in another module I wrote a data generator that populated Sheet1 and Sheet2. Here is the content of that module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Setup()
    SetupSheet "Sheet1", 5
    SetupSheet "Sheet2", 2.5
End Sub

Sub SetupSheet(nm As String, divisor As Double)
    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(nm)
        .[A2].CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .[B1].Value = "Chart" & Right(nm, 1)
        With .[A1]
            For i = 1 To SimpleTracker
                .Offset(i).Value = i
                .Offset(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=1-EXP(-RC[-1]/" & divisor & ")"
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I then executed Setup() from the VB Editor, and created a third worksheet and activated it.

Then I ran DoItOriginal() from the VB editor, and I did not observe the issue you described. It occurred to me that one possible explanation is that switching back to the Excel user interface from the VBE did something to hide the misbehavior, so I installed a button on the sheet and executed DoItOriginal from there, and still did not observe the behavior in 2010, 2011, or 2013.

On thing I noticed is the line 
    .Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
in the setup for Series 1 probably wants to refer to Sheet2.

Try the code above and see if you still observe the misbehavior. If you do and I don't that might be interesting. If you don't, then the puzzle is how does this arrangement differ from the context in which you do see the misbehavior. Since you didn't post that, I'll wait in suspense. -hth

Comment: A guy above found the issue! I'm not entirely sure why it fixed it, but replacing `With sc.NewSeries` with `With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` fixed my problem. Thank you for putting in so much work though! I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You're most welcome. I'm not sure why it fixed it either. It shouldn't have, as far as I know. Still mysterious, too, is why my version of your code didn't display the misbehavior. Hmmm. It will become clear eventually, I hope. Onward.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
DoEvents
```

After adding each chart element, especially after adding each series.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't seem to work. But I did find an answer above. Thank you for helping!